# form key+value pairs jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way I can access the array of data that the browser compiles on a form submit - before the actual GET/POST operation in js/jq?

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//give me the data array here
});
```

I'm finding myself increasingly using AJAX - I call event.preventDefault(), grab the name/value pairs of all the elements contained in `$(this)` (the form) and then push them to the server via `$.post()`. It's becoming a pain the neck to assemble the data array manually. It would be great if a plugin existed of sorts:

```
$data = $("form").gimmeData();
```

Does something like this exist that supports all the major HTML input elements? Am I approaching this way wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, jQuery has a "serializeArray()" method that does pretty much what you ask for.

It returns an array like:

```
[ { name: "something", value: "whatever" }, { name: "another_one", value: 22 } ]
```

You can turn that into an object like this:

```
var arr = $('#form_id').serializeArray(), obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
  obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
```

If a name appears more than once in a form, then its "value" will be an array of values from the separate fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = $("form").serialize(); // will return query string

$data = $("form").serializeArray(); // will return array
```

([Details here](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$('#form').serializeArray()` method in order to get the array passed to the POST request.

You can then edit the object you receive normally.