# onsubmit refresh html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onsubmit

I'm trying to use Javascript to submit the form's data. Here's the html.

```
<form onsubmit="post();">
//input fields here
</form>
```

Here's the Javascript for the `post()` function.

```
var post = function() {
alert('the form was submitted');
return false;
}
```

My issue is that the Javascript runs but the form still processes and refreshes the page..

I put the `return false;` code in hoping it would stop the form from refreshing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to put the return false part after the post() function in the onsubmit handler, like so:

```
<form onsubmit="post();return false;">
//input fields here
</form>
```

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work! But it's working now, thanks anyway!

Comment: Weird that it didn't work before. Could be some syntax error the first time around. Glad it's working now, though, happy to help!

Comment: `<form onsubmit="return post();">` is even better, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Keep your js out of the DOM.

```
<form id="myform" action="somepage.php" method="post">
//input fields
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event){
    alert('submitted');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually return false from your inline dom-0 handler.  So change

```
onsubmit = "post();">
```

to

```
onsubmit = "return post();">
```

---

Or you could give your form an id and do this:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit = "post();">
```

Then from a safe location in which your dom is ready:

```
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = post;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you added the `jQuery` tag, this it the best way to do this:
unobtrusive event attach

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        alert('the form was submitted');
        return false;
    });
```

In your's way it should be;

```
<form onsubmit="return post();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this post is tagged with jQuery, I'll offer the following solution:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  //prevent the form from actually submitting.
  e.preventDefault();
  //specify the url you want to post to.
  //optionally, you could grab the url using $(this).attr('href');
  var url = "http://mysite.com/sendPostVarsHere";
  //construct an object to send to the server
  //optionally, you could grab the input values of the form using $(this).serializeArray()
  var postvars = {};
  //call jquery post with callback function
  $.post(url, postvars, function(response){
    //do something with the response
    console.log(response);
  }, 'json')
});
```

Comment: If you choose to use serializeArray(), assign it to a variable and execute [Pointy's Array -> Object function here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867441/form-keyvalue-pairs-jquery-plugin#answer-7867459) before submitting it to the server.