# Adding a New Value to State is Overwriting Previous State in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

My reducer adds a new workout object to an array called workouts. It works perfectly fine on the first initial change. The problem is when I try to add another workout my reducer overwrites the previous workout I just added.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with my reducer and how I'm manipulating the workouts array.

Form to add a new Workout:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

let Form = props => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <Field name='name' component='input' type='text' />
            <label>Total Calories</label>
            <Field name='calories' component='input' type='number' />
            <label>Duration</label>
            <Field name='duration' component='input' type='number' />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default reduxForm({ form: 'workout' })(Form);
```

actions.js (my action):

```
export const addWorkout = workout => ({
    type: 'ADD_WORKOUT',
    payload: {
        workout,
    },
});
```

workouts.js (reducer):

```
const initialState = {
    workouts: [
        {
            name: 'HIIT',
            calories: '320',
            duration: '30',
        },
        {
            name: 'Run',
            calories: '35',
            duration: '400',
        },
    ],
    totalCal: 0,
};

export default function workoutReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_WORKOUT': {
            console.log(state.workouts);
            return {
                ...state,
                workouts: [...state.workouts, action.payload.workout],
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

[Before adding any workouts, initial state contains two workouts, HIIT and Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/612Gw.png)

[After adding a workout, in this case I added a Yoga workout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLMdh.png)

[Adding a second workout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Gka.png)

As you can see my first workout I added was overwritten.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Here is my component that displays the list of workouts.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Dashboard.scss';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Chart from './Chart';
import Plan from './Plan';

const Dashboard = props => {
    return (
        <div className='dashboard-container'>
            <div className='daily'>
                <h4>Keep it going Steven you got this!</h4>
                <div className='stats'>
                    <p className='calories'>Calories</p>
                    <p className='stand'>Stand Hours </p>
                    <p className='exercise'>Exercise Minutes</p>
                </div>
                <p>Workouts</p>
                {props.workouts.map((workout, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <p key={i}>{workout.name}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
            <div className='workouts'>
                <Chart />
                <Plan />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    workouts: state.workouts.workouts,
    totalCals: state.workouts.totalCal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with this at first glance. Have you tried redux dev tools? Seeing exactly what happens on the second action would be useful. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Comment: Maybe you can try `<form onSubmit={() => { handleSubmit(); return false; }}>`, I think is onSubmit of html `<form>` will refresh the page, so you could not saw the result.  About onSubmit of `<form>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181862/onsubmit-refresh-html-form

Comment: Also think the reducer looks fine. Might be an issue in the component listing the workouts possibly?

Comment: @timotgl I added the component that displays the list of workouts. Still not sure what's wrong though.

Comment: It will take more debugging, but I think the place to look at is in terms of updating the array, it is different than updating objects. It may be worth updating the array using push, rather than the spread operator. Could you please try to use push ? or try to concat ? state.workouts.concat(action.payload.workout) - this should return a new array which should update the state in the right way.

Comment: @AlthafM Is this how I should be using concat? It's still not working as expected.

 `return {...state, workouts: state.workouts.concat(action.payload.workout)}`

Comment: @Steven Add some console.logs in the reducer where ADD_WORKOUT is handled. compare the old state to the new state that will be returned. At some point you'll notice a discrepancy.

Comment: @Steven yes , that should work, but I would create a new const out of the merged one and pass it to the workouts property of state.  yes and I agree with timotgl, console.log or debugging is the only way to understand , usually this has to do with the way react handle object references and array references. Are you seeing that the state is not being updated at all ?

Comment: @AlthafM I checked using console logs and found that my state isn't being updated at all. Do you guys have any idea why this might be?

Comment: I know I am manipulating the state and returning the new state correctly but once I call the reducer again it reverts back to the initial state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was regarding my Add Workout link in the Navbar. Instead of using Link from react-router-dom I was just using a Nav.Link tag from bootstrap which reset my state every time I navigated to the form.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Nav className='mr-auto'>
    ...
    {/* <Nav.Link href='/addworkout'>Add Workout</Nav.Link>  */}
    <Link to='/addworkout'>Add Workout</Link>
</Nav>
```